# Who animated which transformation sequence in Symphogear XV?

Tags: senki-zesshou-symphogear

So I hear that in Symphogear XV, every transformation sequence [was animated by different animator](https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/cdka4x/kirikas_sexy_transformation_sequence_from/etv14ej/). Who animated which transformation?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Anime Staff Database Wiki (Japanese)](https://seesaawiki.jp/w/radioi_34/d/%C0%EF%C9%B1%C0%E4%BE%A7%A5%B7%A5%F3%A5%D5%A5%A9%A5%AE%A5%A2XV), known transformation scene animator(s) (変身原画) *per episode*:

1. **Hibiki**: Yoshitake Nakakoji (中小路佳毅) ([tweet](https://twitter.com/anchareas/status/1147554204434612224))

   > シンフォギア1話　響変身バンクの原画をやらせていただきました。
   >
   > Symphogear ep. 1, I was allowed to do Hibiki's transformation scene.
2. **Kirika**: Yoshiyuki Okubo (大久保義之)
3. **Shirabe & Chris**:

   - Kouki Shikiji (式地幸喜)
   - Yousuke Kabashima (椛島洋介)
4. **Maria**: Hanyu (ハニュー):
5. **Tsubasa**: Hiroyuki Takashima (髙嶋宏之)
6. -
7. **Elfnein/Carol**: Shota Sannomiya (三宮昌太)
8. **Miku**: Kousuke Yoshida (吉田亘良)
9. -
10. -
11. -
12. -
13. -